# How do your write a function that returns values from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I created this array:

```
var lineData = [ { "x": 25,   "y": 75},  { "x": 85,   "y": 130},
             { "x": 140,  "y": 190}, { "x": 195,  "y": 245},
             { "x": 195,  "y": 300}, { "x": 25,  "y": 350},
             { "x": 80,  "y": 405}, { "x": 195,  "y": 460}];
```

Now I want to draw ellipses on the coordinates in the array. How do I create a function that will access the x and y values? How do functions work?

```
// Draw ellipses 
var circle = svgContainer.append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; }})
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("rx", 5)
    .attr("ry", 5);
```

Comment: *"How do functions work?"* - [Learn JavaScript](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-javascript). Read [about functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a loop to access the data (as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232949/5768908)) in a D3 code is a **terrible** idea: not only this is completely unnecessary, but it goes against the very concept of D3 data join, and it will make things awkward later on (if you try to manipulate/change that selection). If you will fix this with a loop, why are you using D3 in the first place? The solution you accepted is completely *non-idiomatic*.

You **don't need** a loop. Simply bind the data and use an "enter" selection, accessing the datum for each circle with the first parameter of the anonymous function: that's the famous `function(d)` in D3. When you do this...

```
.attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x})
//first parameter ---^
```

... the datum for each element will be passed to the `attr` function. In case you want to know, the second parameter is the index and the third parameter is the current group. Also, the actual name of the parameter doesn't matter, only its order.

Here is an example using your data:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 500);
  
var lineData = [ { "x": 25,   "y": 75},  { "x": 85,   "y": 130},
  { "x": 140,  "y": 190}, { "x": 195,  "y": 245},
  { "x": 195,  "y": 300}, { "x": 25,  "y": 350},
  { "x": 80,  "y": 405}, { "x": 195,  "y": 460}];
             
var ellipses = svg.selectAll("faraday")
  .data(lineData)
  .enter()
  .append("ellipse")
  .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x})
  .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y})
  .attr("rx", 5)
  .attr("ry", 5)
  .attr("fill", "teal");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok I tried your answer and it worked too. What's the purpose of having `svg.selectAll("faraday")`?  From my understanding, to draw an ellipse you would use `svg.append("ellipse")`

Comment: With all due respect to the other user (this is not personal), my answer doesn't *"work too"*: the code in my answer is the **idiomatic** D3. Regarding the "Faraday", since you can select things that don't exist in an enter selection ([have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201705290654526256979)), I'm paying a tribute to a different scientist in each S.O. snippet I write. And, as you can see, we don't have to use `selectAll("ellipse")` in the enter selection to append an ellipse.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado First things first, you are absolutely correct, this is the road to go! Regarding your way of acquiring empty selections, though, I am a bit uneasy. I have seen your references to scientists in some of your recent snippets and have always thought, that they might raise more questions than they actually do answer. If Mike Bostock did this kind of stuff in his Blocks, I would thank him for the little conundrum and for the insights gained by tracking it down. On a Q&A site like this, however, I think most people searching for answers to their problems won't get the pun. This...

Comment: ...will only spark comments or follow-up questions on "Why can I select faraday in SVG?". To appeal to your teaching roots: please, give it a second though and consider doing a `svg.selectAll()`, `svg.selectAll(null)` or `svg.selectAll(undefined)` instead, which all will yield an empty selection which can be used to bind data to.

Comment: I've been doing this for months, using `selectAll("foo")`, on purpose, to show people that they don't need to select all circle to append circles, as you know better than me. However, `selectAll("foo")` was not attracting any attention, because I never had a *"what is that foo?"*. Then, I started to use scientists and, every time OP asks why, I share [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201705290904432531602) from the Docs. So, the explanation is clear for future readers.

Comment: @altocumulus on a second thought, I liked `selectAll(null)`... I think it better tells the newbies OPs that the enter selection doesn't need to match any DOM element. I'll use `selectAll(null)` from now on.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Plus, it is way faster: https://jsperf.com/d3-empty-selection. Please pay attention to the tests' details, as I assembled this especially for you ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus yes, I was thinking exactly about this, since it does not (or should not) traverse the DOM. Also, I want to say: Copernicus rules! :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `forEach` method to go through every element in an array and get the values in each.

```
lineData.forEach(function(d) {
    // Draw an elipse
});
```

Put your code inside the brackets, use `d.x` and `d.y` to access coordinates in each element in the array.

Comment: Thanks! What's the purpose of  function(d) ? What does "d" stand for and what does it do?

Comment: @marcos `forEach` will execute a function given to it as parameter for each element in the array, and pass to that function one of the elements in the array. In this case we pass it an anonymous function (`function(d) {}`), `forEach` passes the first element in the array to our anonymous function, so `d` is now equal to the first element in the array (and then it loops and goes through every element in the array). You can then run your code and manipulate it based on whatever `d` is.