# How to manipulate nodes based on dynamicaly changing text? (enter/exit/update)

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3.js with the force layout. Now, with the help of the dynamically changing array `data` it is possible to highlight nodes dynamically based on the array. Also with the code below i am able to show up dynamically the names of the nodes, which are part of the array, as a text.

So, when the array has for example 3 entries, then 3 nodes are shown up and also 3 names of the nodes appear. Let's say their names are "a", "b", "c", so the text "a", "b", "c" appears on screen.
Now, when i click on the new appeared text "a", then i want the node, which contains that name, to be filled green. I tried this with the function called `specialfunction`. The problem is, that all nodes fill green when i click
on the text "a". Can someone of you guys maybe help? Thanks.

```
 var texts = svg.selectAll(".texts")
        .data(data);


    textsExit = texts.exit().remove();

    textsEnter = texts.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "texts");

    textsUpdate = texts.merge(textsEnter)
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 16)
        .text(d => d.name)
        .on("click", specialfunction);

  function specialfunction(d) { 


         node.style("fill", function(d){ return this.style.fill = 'green';});

             };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your `specialFunction` function is only taking the `nodes` selection and setting the style of all its elements to the returned value of...

```
this.style.fill = 'green';
```

... which is, guess what, `"green"`.

Instead of that, `filter` the nodes according to the clicked text:

```
function specialFunction(d) {
    nodes.filter(function(e) {
        return e === d
    }).style("fill", "forestgreen")
}
```

In this simple demo, `d` is the number for both texts and circles. Just change `d` in my demo to `d.name` or any other property you want. Click the text and the correspondent circle will change colour:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = d3.range(5);
var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 30 + d * 45
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "lightblue")
  .attr("stroke", "gray");

var texts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("y", 88)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return 26 + d * 45
  })
  .attr("fill", "dimgray")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .on("click", specialFunction);

function specialFunction(d) {
  nodes.filter(function(e) {
    return e === d
  }).style("fill", "forestgreen")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

EDIT: Answering your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296937/how-to-manipulate-nodes-based-on-dynamicaly-changing-text-enter-exit-update#comment75610053_44301198), this even simpler function can set the circles to the original colour:

```
function specialFunction(d) {
    nodes.style("fill", function(e){
        return e === d ? "forestgreen" : "lightblue"; 
    })
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = d3.range(5);
var nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 30 + d * 45
  })
  .attr("r", 20)
  .style("fill", "lightblue")
  .attr("stroke", "gray");

var texts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("y", 88)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return 26 + d * 45
  })
  .attr("fill", "dimgray")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .on("click", specialFunction);

function specialFunction(d) {
  nodes.style("fill", function(e){
  return e === d ? "forestgreen" : "lightblue"; 
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks again, almighty Gerardo! In your case, the circles remains green when i click on another second number. Is there a chance that the circle return to the original color, when click on a new number?

Comment: Also, for what is `selectAll(null)` good? Why not leave out the selectAll in general?

Comment: To understand the `null`, please read the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233173/5768908

Comment: Regarding turning the circles to the original colour, there are several solutions here at S.O. If you don't find any, please post another question.

Comment: @DerickKolln Please check the edit, I just made the change you asked for.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado `selectAll(null)`—Told you ;-)